# Clear API Gateway Resource Policy using CDK

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I successfully set a Resource Policy using RestApiBaseProps.policy. However trying to clear it by passing 'undefined' didn't clear it out after deploying the API. I went into the Resource Policy editor and it was still there. Unfortunately there is no documentation describing how to do this, I assume passing 'undefined' is how.

Comment: It seems to be bug with CloudFormation: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/21840

Comment: Nice to see it being worked on.